# Remix: Routes starting with "@" like `@username`

Tags: remix.run

How do you implement routes in the form of `@username` so that if I went to my sites `/@test` route, it would display the route corresponding the to `test` username?

Currently I have a file under `app/routes/@username/index.tsx` which uses `const { username } = useParams();` but going to that path gives me a 404.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently a bug in the React Router version that Remix uses. It doesn't match routes that start with non-alphanumeric characters.

I believe that's fixed in the latest React Router version. The team is working on porting Remix on top of the new RR 6.4 data features. A lot of Remix features were moved to React Router.

Right now, Remix is pinned to React Router 6.3. I've taken the fix from 6.4 and backported to 6.3 via `patch-package`. It works fine in dev, but the production bundle is minified. Ugh! I hate it when the minify npm packages. Let the app minifiy during the build!!!

Looks like I'll have to build RR 6.3 with the patch included. Anyway, here's the link to the patch that you can use in dev. I'll try to get to the production version in over the next few days.

https://gist.github.com/kiliman/1a8eb57a6558c96d292bb913add5a178